# select all checkbox click not working on dynamically created checkbox element

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, multi-select

I am using this multiselect plugin. https://github.com/mneofit/multiselect

Issue: when I click on select all checkbox it selects all checkbox except dynamic created checkbox element.
When I click on select all checkbox it should be checked dynamic created checkbox but it is not happening

please help

Here is my code
**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pure js multiselect demo</title>

    <link href="styles/multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* example of setting the width for multiselect */
        #testSelect1_multiSelect {
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="inline_content">
<p>Condesnsing Unit</p>
    <form class="type">
        <input type="radio" name="condesnsing_type" checked="checked" value="208-230/1/60">208-230/1/60</input>
        <input type="radio" name="condesnsing_type" value="460/3/60">460/3/60</input>
    </form>
</div>
<select id='testSelect1' multiple>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2' selected>Item 2</option>
    <option value='3' selected>Item 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Item 5</option>
</select>

<div>
    <button class="test">add</button>
    <button onclick="disable()">Disable</button>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#inline_content input[name='condesnsing_type']").change(function(){

    if($('input:radio[name=condesnsing_type]:checked').val() == "460/3/60"){
    //
        addNewOptionInDropdown();
                }
});

//custom
function addNewOptionInDropdown(){
   var item = 'Val 105-6';
            var myOptionsGreen = [{name:item, value:'val-105-6'}];
            var mySelect = $('#testSelect1');
            $.each(myOptionsGreen, function(index, value) {
            
                mySelect.append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                var id = '&quot;'+jQuery('.multiselect-checkbox').length+'&quot;';
                var indexnumber = '&quot;'+(jQuery('.multiselect-checkbox').length - 1)+'&quot;';
                var itemName = '&quot;'+value.name+'&quot;';
                var attributes = '{&quot;id&quot;:'+id+',&quot;index&quot;:'+indexnumber+',&quot;text&quot;:'+itemName+',&quot;selected&quot;:false,&quot;selectElement&quot;:{},&quot;multiselectElement&quot;:{}}';
                var addliElement = '<li style="display: block;"><label><input class="multiselect-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-val="'+value.value+'" data-multiselect-element="'+attributes+'"><span class="multiselect-text">'+value.name+'</span></label></li>';
                
                $('#testSelect1_itemList ul').append(addliElement);

            });
            

}

</script>
<script>

        

        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setCheckBoxClick("checkboxAll", function(target, args) {
            console.log("Checkbox 'Select All' was clicked and got value ", args.checked);
        })
        .setCheckBoxClick("1", function(target, args) {
            console.log("Checkbox for item with value '1' was clicked and got value ", args.checked);
        });

    function enable() {
        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setIsEnabled(true);
    }

    function disable() {
        document.multiselect('#testSelect1').setIsEnabled(false);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Here is **multiselect js** file

```
if (!m_helper) {
    var m_helper = {
        removeNode: function (id) {
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            if (el) {
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }
        },
        insertAfter: function (item, target) {
            var parent = target.parentNode;
            if (target.nextElementSibling) {
                parent.insertBefore(item, target.nextElementSibling);
            } else {
                parent.appendChild(item);
            }
        },
        hide: function (element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        },
        hideAll: function (array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                this.hide(array[i]);
            }
        },
        show: function (element) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        },
        showAll: function (array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                this.show(array[i]);
            }
        },
        parent: function (element, id) {
            var parent = element.parentElement;
            while (parent && parent.tagName != "BODY") {
                if (parent.id == id) {
                    return parent;
                }
                parent = parent.parentElement;
            }
            return null;
        },
        create: function (data) {
            var result = document.createElement(data.tag);
            if (data.id) {
                result.id = data.id;
            }
            if (data.class) {
                result.className = data.class;
            }
            if (data.attributes) {
                for (var prop in data.attributes) {
                    result.setAttribute(prop, data.attributes[prop]);
                }
            }
            if (data.data) {
                for (var prop in data.data) {
                    result.dataset[prop] = data.data[prop];
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
        div: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "div";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        label: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "label";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        textField: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "input";
            if (!data.attributes) data.attributes = new Object();
            data.attributes.type = "text";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        checkbox: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                data = new Object();
            }
            data.tag = "input";
            if (!data.attributes) data.attributes = new Object();
            data.attributes.type = "checkbox";
            return this.create(data);
        },
        each: function (array, handler) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                handler(array[i]);
            }
        },
        setActive: function (element) {
            element.classList.add("active");
        },
        setUnactive: function (element) {
            element.classList.remove("active");
        },
        select: function (element) {
            element.selected = !0;
            element.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        },
        deselect: function (element) {
            element.selected = !1;
            element.removeAttribute("selected");
        },
        check: function (element) {
            element.checked = !0;
        },
        uncheck: function (element) {
            element.checked = !1;
        },
        click: function (element) {
            if (element.fireEvent) {
                el.fireEvent("onclick");
            } else {
                var evObj = document.createEvent("Events");
                evObj.initEvent("click", !0, !1);
                element.dispatchEvent(evObj);
            }
        },
        setDisabled: function (element, value) {
            element.disabled = value;
        },
    };
}
function Multiselect(item, opts) {
    if ((typeof $ != "undefined" && !$(item).is("select")) || (typeof $ == "undefined" && item.tagName != "SELECT")) {
        throw "Multiselect: passed object must be a select";
    }
    if ((typeof $ != "undefined" && !$(item).attr("multiple")) || (typeof $ == "undefined" && !item.hasAttribute("multiple"))) {
        throw "Multiselect: passed object should contain 'multiple' attribute";
    }
    this._item = item;
    this._createUI();
    this._appendEvents();
    this._initSelectedFields();
    this._initIsEnabled();
}
Multiselect.prototype = {
    _createUI: function () {
        m_helper.removeNode(this._getIdentifier());
        var wrapper = this._createWrapper();
        m_helper.insertAfter(wrapper, this._item);
        wrapper.appendChild(this._createInputField());
        wrapper.appendChild(this._createItemList());
        m_helper.hide(this._item);
    },
    _createWrapper: function () {
        var result = document.createElement("div");
        result.className = "multiselect-wrapper";
        result.id = this._getIdentifier();
        return result;
    },
    _createInputField: function () {
        var input = m_helper.textField({ id: this._getInputFieldIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-input", attributes: { autocomplete: "off" } }),
            label = m_helper.label({ id: this._getInputBadgeIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-count", attributes: { for: this._getInputFieldIdentifier() } }),
            dropDownArrow = m_helper.label({ class: "multiselect-dropdown-arrow", attributes: { for: this._getInputFieldIdentifier() } }),
            result = m_helper.div({ class: "multiselect-input-div" });
        label.style.visibility = "hidden";
        label.innerHTML = 0;
        result.appendChild(input);
        result.appendChild(label);
        result.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
        return result;
    },
    _createItemList: function () {
        var list = m_helper.create({ tag: "ul" });
        var self = this;
        m_helper.each(this._getItems(this._item), function (e) {
            var insertItem = self._createItem("li", e.id, e.text, e.selected);
            list.appendChild(insertItem);
            var checkBox = insertItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
            e.multiselectElement = checkBox;
            checkBox.dataset.multiselectElement = JSON.stringify(e);
        });
        var selectAll = this._createItem("span", -1, "Select all");
        var result = m_helper.div({ id: this._getItemListIdentifier(), class: "multiselect-list" });
        result.appendChild(selectAll);
        result.appendChild(m_helper.create({ tag: "hr" }));
        result.appendChild(list);
        return result;
    },
    _createItem: function (wrapper, value, text, selected) {
        var checkBox = m_helper.checkbox({ class: "multiselect-checkbox", data: { val: value } }),
            textBox = m_helper.create({ tag: "span", class: "multiselect-text" }),
            result = m_helper.create({ tag: wrapper }),
            label = m_helper.label();
        textBox.className = "multiselect-text";
        textBox.innerHTML = text;
        label.appendChild(checkBox);
        label.appendChild(textBox);
        result.appendChild(label);
        return result;
    },
    _initSelectedFields: function () {
        var itemResult = this._getItems().filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.selected;
        });
        if (itemResult.length != 0) {
            var self = this;
            m_helper.each(itemResult, function (e) {
                self.select(e.id);
            });
        }
        this._hideList(this);
    },
    _initIsEnabled: function () {
        this.setIsEnabled(!this._item.disabled);
    },
    destroy() {
        m_helper.removeNode(this._getIdentifier());
        m_helper.show(this._item);
        var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(this._item);
        if (index > -1) {
            window.multiselects._items.splice(index, 1);
            window.multiselects.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
    select: function (val) {
        this._toggle(val, !0);
    },
    deselect: function (val) {
        this._toggle(val, !1);
    },
    setIsEnabled(isEnabled) {
        if (this._isEnabled === isEnabled) return;
        var wrapperItem = document.getElementById(this._getIdentifier());
        if (isEnabled) {
            wrapperItem.classList.remove("disabled");
        } else {
            wrapperItem.classList.add("disabled");
        }
        m_helper.setDisabled(this._item, !isEnabled);
        m_helper.setDisabled(document.getElementById(this._getInputFieldIdentifier()), !isEnabled);
        this._isEnabled = isEnabled;
    },
    _toggle: function (val, setCheck) {
        var self = this;
        if (val) {
            m_helper.each(document.getElementById(this._getIdentifier()).querySelectorAll(".multiselect-checkbox"), function (e) {
                if (e.dataset.val == val) {
                    if (setCheck && !e.checked) {
                        m_helper.check(e);
                        self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self);
                    } else if (!setCheck && e.checked) {
                        m_helper.uncheck(e);
                        self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self);
                    }
                }
            });
            self._updateText(self);
        }
    },
    selectAll: function (val) {
        var selectAllChkBox = document.querySelector("#" + this._getIdentifier() + " .multiselect-checkbox");
        m_helper.check(selectAllChkBox);
        this._onCheckBoxChange(selectAllChkBox, this);
        this._updateText(this);
    },
    deselectAll: function () {
        var selectAllChkBox = document.querySelector("#" + this._getIdentifier() + " .multiselect-checkbox");
        m_helper.uncheck(selectAllChkBox);
        this._onCheckBoxChange(selectAllChkBox, this);
        this._updateText(this);
    },
    _checkboxClickEvents: {},
    setCheckBoxClick(id, handler) {
        if (typeof handler === "function") {
            this._checkboxClickEvents[id] = handler;
        } else {
            console.error("Checkbox click handler for checkbox value=" + id + " is not a function");
        }
        return this;
    },
    _appendEvents: function () {
        var self = this;
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
            self._showList(self);
            document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = "";
            m_helper.each(window.multiselects, function (e) {
                if (document.getElementById(e._getItemListIdentifier()).offsetParent && m_helper.parent(event.target, e._getIdentifier())) {
                    e._hideList(self);
                }
            });
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("click", function () {
            self._showList(self);
            document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = "";
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getIdentifier()).addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            if (m_helper.parent(target, self._getIdentifier())) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        document.getElementById(self._getItemListIdentifier()).addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            self._showList(self);
        });
        /* m_helper.each(document.getElementById(self._getIdentifier()).querySelectorAll(".multiselect-checkbox"), function (e) {
            e.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                self._onCheckBoxChange(e, self, event);
            });
        }); */
        //console.log(document.getElementById("testSelect1_multiSelect").querySelectorAll(".multiselect-checkbox"));
            jQuery("#testSelect1_multiSelect").on("change", ".multiselect-checkbox", function(e) {
                self._onCheckBoxChange(e.target, self, event);
            });
        var onInput = function () {
            var text = this.value.toLowerCase();
            if (!text || text == "") {
                m_helper.show(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > span"));
                m_helper.show(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > hr"));
                m_helper.showAll(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li"));
            } else {
                m_helper.hide(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > span"));
                m_helper.hide(document.querySelector("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " > hr"));
                var array = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li span"), function (obj) {
                    return obj.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
                });
                m_helper.hideAll(document.querySelectorAll("#" + self._getItemListIdentifier() + " li"));
                m_helper.each(array, function (e) {
                    m_helper.show(e.parentElement.parentElement);
                });
            }
        };
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("propertychange", onInput);
        document.getElementById(self._getInputFieldIdentifier()).addEventListener("input", onInput);
    },
    _onCheckBoxChange: function (checkbox, self, event) {
        if (!checkbox.dataset.multiselectElement) {
            var checkedState = self._performSelectAll(checkbox, self);
            if (typeof self._checkboxClickEvents.checkboxAll === "function") {
                self._checkboxClickEvents.checkboxAll(checkbox, { checked: checkedState });
            }
        } else {
            var checkedState = self._performSelectItem(checkbox, self);
            if (typeof self._checkboxClickEvents[checkedState.id] === "function") {
                self._checkboxClickEvents[checkedState.id](checkbox, checkedState);
            }
            self._updateSelectAll(self);
        }
        self._forceUpdate();
    },
    _performSelectItem: function (checkbox, self) {
        var item = JSON.parse(checkbox.dataset.multiselectElement);
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            self._itemCounter++;
            m_helper.select(this._item.options[item.index]);
            m_helper.setActive(checkbox.parentElement.parentElement);
            return { id: item.id, checked: !0 };
        }
        self._itemCounter--;
        m_helper.deselect(this._item.options[item.index]);
        m_helper.setUnactive(checkbox.parentElement.parentElement);
        return { id: item.id, checked: !1 };
    },
    _performSelectAll: function (checkbox, self) {
        var items = self._getItems();
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            self._itemCounter = items.length;
            m_helper.each(items, function (e) {
                m_helper.setActive(e.multiselectElement.parentElement.parentElement);
                m_helper.select(self._item.options[e.index]);
                m_helper.check(e.multiselectElement);
            });
            return !0;
        }
        self._itemCounter = 0;
        m_helper.each(items, function (e) {
            e.multiselectElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
            m_helper.deselect(self._item.options[e.index]);
            m_helper.uncheck(e.multiselectElement);
        });
        return !1;
    },
    _updateSelectAll: function (self) {
        var allChkBox = document.getElementById(self._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
        if (self._itemCounter == self._getItems().length) {
            allChkBox.checked = !0;
        } else if (allChkBox.checked) {
            allChkBox.checked = !1;
        }
    },
    _hideList: function (context, event) {
        m_helper.setUnactive(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()));
        m_helper.show(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("span"));
        m_helper.show(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelector("hr"));
        m_helper.showAll(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("li"));
        context._updateText(context);
        if (event) event.stopPropagation();
    },
    _updateText: function (context) {
        var activeItems = document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("ul .active");
        if (activeItems.length > 0) {
            var val = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < (activeItems.length < 5 ? activeItems.length : 5); i++) {
                val += activeItems[i].innerText + ", ";
            }
            val = val.substr(0, val.length - 2);
            if (val.length > 20) {
                val = val.substr(0, 17) + "...";
            }
        }
        if (activeItems.length == document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()).querySelectorAll("ul li").length) {
            val = "All selected";
        }
        document.getElementById(context._getInputFieldIdentifier()).value = val ? val : "";
    },
    _showList: function (context) {
        m_helper.setActive(document.getElementById(context._getItemListIdentifier()));
    },
    _forceUpdate: function () {
        var badge = document.getElementById(this._getInputBadgeIdentifier());
        badge.style.visibility = "hidden";
        if (this._itemCounter != 0) {
            badge.innerHTML = this._itemCounter;
            badge.style.visibility = "visible";
            var ddArrow = badge.nextElementSibling;
            if (this._itemCounter < 10) {
                badge.style.left = "-45px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-42px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 100) {
                badge.style.left = "-50px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-47px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 1000) {
                badge.style.left = "-55px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-52px";
            } else if (this._itemCounter < 10000) {
                badge.style.left = "-60px";
                ddArrow.style.marginLeft = "-57px";
            }
        }
    },
    _items: undefined,
    _itemCounter: 0,
    _isEnabled: !0,
    _getItems: function () {
        if (this._items == undefined) {
            var result = [];
            var opts = this._item.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
                var insertItem = { id: opts[i].value, index: i, text: opts[i].innerHTML, selected: !!opts[i].selected, selectElement: opts[i] };
                result.push(insertItem);
            }
            this._items = result;
        }
        return this._items;
    },
    _getItemUniqueIdentifier: function () {
        var id = this._item.getAttribute("id"),
            name = this._item.getAttribute("name");
        if (!(id || name)) {
            throw "Multiselect: object does not contain any identifier (id or name)";
        }
        return id ? id : name;
    },
    _getIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_multiSelect";
    },
    _getInputFieldIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_input";
    },
    _getItemListIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_itemList";
    },
    _getInputBadgeIdentifier: function () {
        return this._getItemUniqueIdentifier() + "_inputCount";
    },
};
window.multiselects = [];
if (typeof $ != "undefined") {
    $.fn.multiselect = function () {
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }
        if (this.length != 0) {
            $(this).each(function (i, e) {
                var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
                if (index == -1) {
                    var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                    window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                    window.multiselects._items.push(e);
                    res.push(inputItem);
                } else {
                    res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
                }
            });
        }
        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : $(res);
    };
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    });
} else {
    document.multiselect = function (selector) {
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }
        m_helper.each(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (e) {
            var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
            if (index == -1) {
                var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                window.multiselects._items.push(e);
                res.push(inputItem);
            } else {
                res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
            }
        });
        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : res;
    };
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    };
}
function hideMultiselects(event) {
    m_helper.each(window.multiselects, function (e) {
        if (document.getElementById(e._getItemListIdentifier()).offsetParent && !m_helper.parent(event.target, e._getIdentifier())) {
            e._hideList(e, event);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems here and its not clear what you are trying to achieve. - You aren't creating checkboxes, you are creating options in a select. There is no select all checkbox in your code or html. A checkbox is a <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cbgroup">One</input>

Comment: @Bryn you have to check multiselect js file because that js file create checkboxes

Comment: @Bryn I have created dynamically checkbox in a dropdown but when I click on select all checkbox that one make checked all checkboxes except dynamically created checkbox that’s the problem which I am facing